# Limit string loading by the file_get_contents

Tags: php, limit, file-get-contents

Is there any way to limit a number of characters that are loaded using the `file_get_contents('http://myurl.com/');`?

I need to load only first 500 characters from an URL to save the load time - is that possible?
I've heard about method like this, but dunno if its feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`file_get_contents` has a `maxLen` parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) that does exactly this.

Comment: Not me, but it is pretty obvious you didn't do much research on this, as it was in the documentation.